# Modeling friction in my simple Python physics engine

Tags: python, python-3.x, physics-engine

I have modeled friction in my simple physics engine in Python but it's not the best. My problem is that with certain velocities the object experiences friction and slows down and stops, but after it stops it keeps vibrating back and forth. I think the problem is because the velocity is not decreasing smoothly as it would in real life, it's decreasing in increments of whatever acceleration caused by the force due to friction is.

While trying to make this simple physics engine I've run into two problems, the first one was a problem with boundaries and the second one is with friction. I can solve these but my solutions are not that good, they're sloppy, my solution is kind of like numerical solutions (it's approximate) but your solutions are like analytical solutions (they're perfect) how do I prevent this?

Here is the code.

```
import pygame as pyg
# from math import *
pyg.init()

win = pyg.display.set_mode((1500, 900))

pyg.display.set_caption('physics engine')

mainloop = True
jump = False


class Objects:
    def __init__(self, x, y, vel_x, vel_y, acc_x, acc_y, mass):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.vel_x = vel_x
        self.vel_y = vel_y
        self.acc_x = acc_x
        self.acc_y = acc_y
        self.mass = mass


circ = Objects(400, 750, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100)
rect = Objects(0, 890, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100)

F_x = 1250
F_y = 1750
coeff_fric = 0.3
friction_x = 0
friction_y = 0
g = 9.8

while mainloop:
    pyg.time.delay(50)

    for event in pyg.event.get():
        if event.type == pyg.QUIT:
            mainloop = False
    keys = pyg.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pyg.K_LEFT]:
        circ.acc_x = -1 * F_x / circ.mass

    if keys[pyg.K_RIGHT]:
        circ.acc_x = F_x / circ.mass

    if keys[pyg.K_UP]:
        circ.acc_y = -1 * F_y / circ.mass

    if keys[pyg.K_DOWN]:
        circ.acc_y = F_y / circ.mass

    if keys[pyg.K_SPACE]:
        circ.vel_y = 0
        circ.vel_x = 0

    circ.vel_y += g
    circ.vel_x += circ.acc_x
    circ.vel_x += circ.acc_x
    circ.vel_y += circ.acc_y
    circ.vel_y += circ.acc_y

    win.fill((0, 0, 0))

    circ.x += circ.vel_x
    circ.y += circ.vel_y
    if circ.x < 50 or circ.x > 1450:
        circ.x = max(50, min(1450, circ.x))
        circ.vel_x = 0
    if circ.y < 50 or circ.y > 840:
        circ.y = max(50, min(840, circ.y))
        circ.vel_y = 0
    F_x = 1250
    F_y = 1750
    circ.acc_x = 0
    circ.acc_y = 0
    friction_x = coeff_fric * circ.mass * g
    friction_y = coeff_fric * circ.mass * g
    fric_force_x = F_x - friction_x
    fric_force_y = F_y - friction_y
    if circ.y >= 840:
        if circ.acc_x == 0:
            if round(circ.vel_x) == 0:
                circ.vel_x = 0
            if round(circ.vel_x) > 0:
                circ.acc_x = -1 * friction_x / circ.mass
                circ.vel_x += circ.acc_x
                if circ.vel_x < 0:
                    circ.vel_x = 0
                    circ.acc_x = 0
            if round(circ.vel_x) < 0:
                circ.acc_x = friction_x / circ.mass
                circ.vel_x += circ.acc_x
                if circ.vel_x > 0:
                    circ.vel_x = 0
                    circ.acc_x = 0

    print(circ.vel_x)
    objct = pyg.draw.circle(win, (50, 50, 255), (round(circ.x), round(circ.y)), 50)
    floor = pyg.draw.rect(win, (150, 75, 0), (rect.x, rect.y, 1500, 10))

    pyg.display.update()

pyg.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're double adding the acceleration. Once I took out the extra adds, the jitter stopped.

```
circ.vel_x += circ.acc_x
#circ.vel_x += circ.acc_x
circ.vel_y += circ.acc_y
#circ.vel_y += circ.acc_y
```

Comment: How do I implement rotation into it? Just simple rotational mechanics. Where do I start? Thank you for pointing the double adding

Comment: Check out rotational inertia: https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/torque-angular-momentum/torque-tutorial/a/rotational-inertia